# Struct copied into byte array .. wrong alignement?

Tags: c, struct, pcap, memory-alignment, arp

I'm trying to send some manually crafted ARP packets over the network,more specifically an ARP request to get the MAC address of a host.
I can't get the final packet right, on wireshark it stills shows some inconsistency. 
Let me walk you through :
Here are the struct & typedef I use all over the program ,
I've defined

- a IP struct ( => in_addr )
- a MAC struct ( => ether_addr )
- a Host struct composed of a MAC & IP
- Custom struct to represent a Ethernet frame & an ARP frame.

The code:

```
#define ETH_ADDR_SIZE 6
#define IP_ADDR_SIZE 4
typedef u_char Packet;
typedef struct in_addr IP;
typedef struct ether_addr MAC;

struct Host {
    IP ip;
    MAC mac;
};
typedef struct pkt_eth {
    MAC dest;
    MAC src;
    u_short type;
} pkt_eth;

typedef struct pkt_arp {
    u_short htype;/* hardware type => ethernet , etc */
    u_short ptype; /*protocol type => ipv4 or ipv6 */
    u_char hard_addr_len; /* usually 6 bytes for ethernet */
    u_char proto_addr_len; /*usually 8 bytes for ipv4 */
    u_short opcode; /* type of arp */
    MAC hard_addr_send;
    IP proto_addr_send;
    MAC hard_addr_dest;
    IP proto_addr_dest;
} pkt_arp;

/* Designate our own MAC / IP addresses of the interface */
extern MAC mac;
extern IP ip;
extern char * interface;

/* Just some vars used to compare with the struct we use */
const MAC broadcast_mac = { 0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff };
const MAC  null_mac = { 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 };
const IP broadcast_ip = { 0xffffffff };
const IP null_ip = { 0x00000000 };
const struct Host null_host = {{ 0x00000000 },
                             { 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 }};

/* Empty mac address which can be used as a temp variable */
MAC tmp_mac = { 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 };
IP tmp_ip = { 0x00000000 };
```

Here is the relevant function :

```
    int
arp_resolve_mac ( struct Host * host )
{
    struct pkt_arp * arp;
    struct pkt_eth * eth;
    /*Create the request packet */
    Packet * request = arp_packet(REQUEST);
    eth = (struct pkt_eth *) (request);
    arp = (struct pkt_arp *) (request + ETH_SIZE);

    /* ethernet frame */
    copy_mac(&eth->dest,&broadcast_mac);
    copy_mac(&eth->src,&mac);

     /* arp request => mac dest address set to null */
    copy_mac(&arp->hard_addr_send,&mac);
    copy_mac(&arp->hard_addr_dest,&null_mac);

    /* arp request => target ip ! */
    copy_ip(&arp->proto_addr_send,&ip);
    copy_ip(&arp->proto_addr_dest,&host->ip);

    /* Set up sniffing. Better to do it before so less 
     * prepare time and if any error occurs, no need to send
     * the packet. less intrusive */
    pcap_init(interface,"arp");
    pcap_set_arp_analyzer(arp_analyzer_resolv);

    /* Sets the tmp ip variable so we will know if it the right
     * response we get or a response coming from another source */
    tmp_ip = host->ip;
    /* sends the packet */
    if(pcap_send_packet(request,ARP_PACKET_SIZE) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error while sending ARP request packet.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    ....
    }
Packet *
arp_packet ( int opcode )
{
    struct pkt_arp * arp;
    struct pkt_eth * eth;
    Packet * bytes = (Packet *) malloc(ARP_PACKET_SIZE);

    if(bytes == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Could not alloc ARP packet.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    eth = (struct pkt_eth *) (bytes);
    eth->type = htons(ETHERTYPE_ARP);

    /* length about hard / proto  ... */
    arp = (struct pkt_arp *) (bytes + ETH_SIZE);
    arp->htype = htons(1);
    arp->ptype = htons(0x0800);
    arp->hard_addr_len = ETH_ADDR_SIZE;
    arp->proto_addr_len = IP_ADDR_SIZE;
    /* reply or request */
    arp->opcode = opcode == REQUEST ? htons(ARPOP_REQUEST) : htons(ARPOP_REPLY);

    return bytes;
}       /* -----  end of function arp_empty  ----- */


void copy_mac(MAC * m1,const MAC * m2) {
    memcpy(m1,m2,ETH_ADDR_SIZE);
}
void copy_ip(IP * i1,const IP * i2) {
    memcpy(i1,i2,IP_ADDR_SIZE);
}
void copy_host(struct Host * h1,const  struct Host * h2) {
    copy_mac(&h1->mac,&h2->mac);
    copy_ip(&h1->ip,&h2->ip);
}
```

**Problem**:
The created packet is not quite right. Everything is fine up to the *hard_addr_send*. After this field, there is 2 bytes 0x00,0x00, (seen in GDB) and then the IP address. But due to this offset, it's impossible to correctly parse this packet. For example,in wireshark, instead of getting "10.0.0.1", I've got "0.0.10.0" for IP. 
Here is the transcript of GDB :

```
/** 14 to pass ethernet frame & 4 + 2 + 2 to go to the addresses section*/
(gdb) x/6xb request+14+4+2+2
/** My MAC address , field hard_addr_send. it's GOOD. */
0x606b16:   0x34    0x67    0x20    0x01    0x9a    0x67
(gdb) x/6xb request+14+4+2+2+6
/** 6bytes later, supposedly my IP address.
* It should be 10.0.0.7 but you can see the 0x0a shifted by 2 bytes */
0x606b1c:   0x00    0x00    0x0a    0x00    0x00    0x07
```

In the method "arp_resolv_mac", everything info is right, i.e. struct Host contains the good information etc; I've checked everything.
I just don't get this offset by 2 bytes ... In a older versions, not using all theses new structs (only char *), I've already succeed at creating a right ARP packet, so I'm kind of wondering if this is not due to the struct, but my knowledge of C does not extend to the memory alignement subject ...!

Thank you.

Comment: In C, the compiler is free to pack or pad the information in a `struct` as it sees fit. So if you want to convert back and forth between a byte array and a `struct`, you will need to copy members over individually to guarantee alignment.

Comment: Is not the "normal alignement" (every member attached each other in the same order as in the definition) the default ?

Comment: They would be in order, but possibly padded. Alignment is affected by padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your structs are not packed. One solution would be to use packed structs, i.e.

```
typedef struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) pkt_arp {
    u_short htype;/* hardware type => ethernet , etc */
    u_short ptype; /*protocol type => ipv4 or ipv6 */
    u_char hard_addr_len; /* usually 6 bytes for ethernet */
    u_char proto_addr_len; /*usually 8 bytes for ipv4 */
    u_short opcode; /* type of arp */
    MAC hard_addr_send;
    IP proto_addr_send;
    MAC hard_addr_dest;
    IP proto_addr_dest;
} pkt_arp;
```

However, that is a gcc-specific extension other compilers may not support.

In my opinion, the best solution is accessing the elements of the byte array directly instead of using structs. Yes, it adds a few lines of code, but it's guaranteed to work for compilers that don't implement packed structs too.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more about this packed attribute ? And I thought by default, struct members were all aligned "correctly",i.e. every members are attached in the same way it's been declared ?

Comment: Ìt works !! THANK YOU a lot !  you saved another memory-inspection torture day ! Maybe i'll change back to plain array then.

Comment: If you define the following struct: struct mystruct { uint16_t x; uint32_t y; } then the length of the struct will be 8 bytes because of the 4-byte alignment requirement of uint32_t. So, it has 2 bytes of x, 2 bytes of padding and 4 bytes of y. If you use packed structs, then the padding is eliminated. The downside is that on some architectures you can't have pointers into members of packed structs.

Comment: Oooooookkkkk . I get it !!! everything was aligned to 4 bytes, and when i put the 6 bytes MAC address, the last two bytes are stored at the memory location of the IP address... THANKS !

Comment: the most generic method is to define all fields as arrays of characters.  then use memcpy() to copy data to/from those fields.